# POST request of rot13 app breaking my app

Tags: google-app-engine, httprequest, rot13

I am following the tutorials on Udacity.com to learn web development and I currently have to build a rot13 app on Google App Engine..

My entire code is shown below even though I believe the error is from `POST function`.
If I comment it out I'm able to see the app even though can't do anything it.

But if I uncomment it, it shows a blank page in my browser.

Hoping to get some pointers on what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

```
import webapp2
import cgi

form="""<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
  </head>

  <body>
   <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
   <form method="post">
    <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;">  </textarea>
   <br>
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
"""


def rot13(a):
    list1 = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    list2 = 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM'
    result = ''
    for e in a:
        if e in list1:
            result = result + list2[list1.find(e)]
        else:
            result = result + e
    return result


def escape_html(s):
  return cgi.escape(s, quote = True)



class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(form)

def post(self):
       rot13 = ''
       text = self.request.get('text')
         if text:
          rot13 = text.encode('rot13')

       self.response.out.write(form, text = rot13)



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Comment: When you see the blank page, the error will be shown in the log. Can you see it in the console? What is it?

Comment: ERROR    2014-07-02 21:24:38,490 wsgi.py:262] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 301, in _LoadHandler

    raise err

ImportError: <module 'helloworld' from 'C:\Users\maxxie\Desktop\helloworld\helloworld.pyc'> has no attribute application

Comment: That looks like you have a helloworld import somewhere in your code that you shouldn't have